# How to create Http Trigger and Time Trigger in one azure function in C#?

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I have this

[image: code]

It has http trigger and time trigger.

Now when I run the azure function it gives me this

[image: error]

What am I doing wrong ?

**(EDIT)**
Just updated my visual studio and build tools to latest version and it solve the problem.

Comment: Invalid Question Description. Provide what you have tried, got any error message and the question isn't clear what the requirement is! Otherwise, the question will be closed.

Comment: The way you created the Http Trigger, is the same for Creating any other triggers where you have to select the type of trigger required in the creation process and configure accordingly. [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-scheduled-function)

Comment: You just do!  Right click, add New Azure Function and select timer trigger.

Comment: do not post images, instead give the text of your code. See SO guideline on [Why should I not upload images of code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)

Comment: So, you need to write both the triggers in same function code?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/XMYyAzd.png - I have taken .NET 6 Azure Functions v4 and made the Function 2 (Timer Trigger as static) and changed the Run method name to Run2, it is working successfully as you can see the screenshot

Comment: @HariKrishna yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my visual studio and build tools were outdated.
So I just updated it the latest version and it solved my issue.
Thank you for all the answers.

Answer (score 0):

I have taken .NET 6 Azure Functions v4 and made the Function 2 (Timer Trigger as static) and changed the Run method name to Run2, it is working successfully as you can see below screenshot:

[image]

And in 2nd practical, tried with your Timer Trigger Code Provided, made changes as did in above with Authorization Level as Function and got the successful result:

[image]

Function Code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace KrishNet6FunApp1040
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            string name = req.Query["name"];

            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
            name = name ?? data?.name;

            string responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)
                ? "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."
                : $"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.";

            return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
        }


        [FunctionName("TimerTriggerCSharp")]
        public static void Run2([TimerTrigger("0 */1 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
        {
            if (myTimer.IsPastDue)
            {
                log.LogInformation("Timer is running late!");
            }
            log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: cant view your images

Comment: Hello @khert, I can see the images. Can you refresh and check again.